# Sending an email from R

Tags: r, email, security

I am using the following code to send an email to my Gmail account.
library(mailR)

```
    sender <- "*********@gmail.com"    
recipients <- c("**********@gmail.com")    
send.mail(from = sender,    
             to = recipients,    
             subject = "Test",    
              body = "Test",    
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,    
                      user.name = "**********@gmail.com",              
                      passwd = "*********", ssl = TRUE),    
          authenticate = TRUE,    
          send = TRUE)
```

I have tried to used different ports also like 25, 522 but nothing works. Also, I have also Enable access to 'less secure apps'. Kindly help.

But I am getting an error:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:348)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.ValiNULL
dator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Answer (score 3):

Since, nobody actually helped me on this issue but I kept on trying and exploring things and got a link/solution to address my issue.

1. Sending an email could be done with sendmailR or mailR package but you need to have the correct SMTP settings (from your IT), otherwise it won't work no matter how much you try. Whatever, I found out regarding mailR nothing worked for me.
2. The other part is to get set up an API and get a client ID for your gmail account and then use this file to build a connection and send email. The link to do it is shown below.

https://github.com/jennybc/send-email-with-r

Hope this helps everyone who faced the issue same as me.